# Object is not extensible in React.js

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am using TypeScript in my project where I have an array of questions coming from the database and in that array, I don't have the property `questionAnswer` and `questionAnswerText`.

questionAnswer and questionAnswerText gets added when the user types on radio button or `textArea`. When in update the array using the index value I get the error:

> Cannot property "propertyName",object is not extensible.

**Looping the questions**

```
 <div className="question-container-main">
            {questionAnswer.map((m: any, index: number) => (
              <QuestionComponent
                totalCount={questionAnswer.length}
                data={{ ...m, questionAnswer: "", questionAnswerText: "" }}
                count={index + 1}
                sendDataToParent={(d: IQuestion, count: number) => {
                  console.log(d);
                  setQuestionAnswer([
                    ...questionAnswer.splice(count - 1, 0, d),
                  ]);
                }}
              />
            ))}
          </div>
```

insert answer is called when user does `onChange` event on HTML element

```
const insertAnswer = (value: string, name: string) => {
    if (props.data.question_type_id === 6) {
      if (name === "radio-buttons-group") {
        props.data.questionAnswer = value;
      } else {
        props.data.questionAnswerText = value;
      }
    } else {
    }
    console.log(props.data);

    props.sendDataToParent(props.data, props.count);
    // if()
  };
```

Interface defined in question Component as

```
interface questionComponentProps {
  data: {
    question_id: number;
    question_type_id: number;
    question: string;
    section_id: number;
    section: string;
    status: number;
    title: string;
    rating_scale: string;
    question_html: string;
    questionAnswer: string;
    questionAnswerText: string;
  };
  count: number;
  totalCount: number;
  sendDataToParent: any;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe what's happening is that you are trying to directly modify the `props` object, which is not valid. A good way to think about it is that the parent component "owns" the `props` object, so react/typescript protects it from being modified by the child. The child logically should have read-only access to props.

**Modify the desired properties using a callback**

What this means is that you pass a function from the parent to the child that the child should call whenever it wants to update these properties. The interface would look something like

```
interface questionComponentProps {
  data: {
    ...
  };
  count: number;
  totalCount: number;
  sendDataToParent: any;
  updateAnswer: (newAnswer: { questionAnswer: string, questionAnswerText: string }) => void; // new prop
}
```

The new prop in question is `updateAnswer: (newAnswer: { questionAnswer: string, questionAnswerText: string }) => void;` Notice it's a function that takes the two props you wish to change and returns void.

From the question, it's not clear how `questionAnswer` is defined in the parent, but it's likely to be a state variable (if not, it makes sense to make it one since it seems to be updated). Then, the parent `div` would need to define this `updateAnswer` prop for each question in the list to take it's index and the new answer and update the state.

Then in the child `div`, instead of trying to directly update `props.data.questionAnswer` you'd use the callback, like

```
props.updateAnswer({
  questionAnswer: "some string",
  questionAnswerText: "some other string",
});
```